# Support of html tags and right-to-left languages in Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, right-to-left

In ipython notebooks we could add html tags inside markdowns. A useful tag for right-to-left languages was `<p dir=rtl> text </p>` that conveniently made the text aligned to right.

Is there a way to add html tags or right-to-left paragraph alignment in Jupyter?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It can be done like this:

```
<div style="direction:rtl"> Right-to-left text </div>
```

Comment: Where is that inserted?