# How to combine markdown format in a right-to-left environment in a jupyter cell

Tags: markdown, right-to-left, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to make a jupyter notebook with rtl language in the markdown cells.
The solution for using rtl is given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35238470/support-of-html-tags-and-right-to-left-languages-in-jupyter)
However, inside the `<div>` environment markdown syntax does not seem to work.
For example:

```
<div style="direction:rtl">

test
====

</div>
```

does not print 'test' highlighted.

Is there a way to combine the two?

Answer (score 1):

The [Syntax Rules](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html) state:

> Note that Markdown formatting syntax is not processed within block-level HTML tags. E.g., you can’t use Markdown-style `*emphasis*` inside an HTML block.

However, some Markdown implementations have included an optional ability to bypass this rule and parse Markdown formatting inside block-level HTML tags. You need to check the documentation for the Markdown implementation you are using and if it includes such an option, enable that option.

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking for specific ways to overcome this issue in jupyter notebook, the markdown implementation of which I was unable to find at its main homepage.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not familiar with that project either (never used it) and I couldn't find any useful info when I looked. However, you might want to try the `markdown=1` method as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35276926/866026). That method is supported by a number of implementations (although some still need it to be enabled). However, as there doesn't appear to be any info about it for your implementation, then perhaps no such support is offered.